# How to extract complete html source code and save it in a text file by using php

Tags: php, html, curl, web, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the source code from a website and want to save it in a text file on wamp server. So kindly help me.

Comment: Take a look at [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: thankx naruto nxt time i will be carefull

Comment: This question (and the answer) actually helped me. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very complicated, you can get the content of a file by calling **file_get_contents()** this includes files on the web.
Then you just need to write the content to a file and presto you have extracted the .html source and saved it in a text file by using php.

```
<?php
    // Open a webpage
    $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
    // echo the homepage to see the content.
    echo $homepage;

    // Set the filename
    $file = 'hp.txt';
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $homepage);
?>
```

Hope this is what you need.